# Latest/best versions of Java and Tomcat for Grails 4?

Tags: grails

Just about to embark on an upgrade of a large Grails 2.2.5 application to Grails 4 (maybe 4.1 by the time it's complete). What are the latest versions of Java and Tomcat which provide a good stable working system with the latest Grails 4? A few months back I used Tomcat 9 and Java 11, but I'm wondering whether things have moved on at all since then.

Answer (score 2):

We used Jdk-11 and Tomcat-9.4.x with grails-4.0.x it works

Comment: Yes, that's what I used a while back. Possibly safest to stick with that for now.

Comment: Do you mean Tomcate-9.0.4x or Tomcat-9.0.45 does Tomcat have a 9.4?  I use the docker image 9.0.45-jdk11-openjdk for Grails 4.

Comment: Sorry typo. its 9.0.45 and 9.0.46

Comment: Is better to use Tomcat than standalone (grails run-app) or runnable WAR or JAR file?